# Редирект после авторизации с использованием cURL.

Tags: ssl, curl, php

С курлом не часто приходиться работать, посему нуждаюсь в вашей помощи. Есть домен, там авторизация идет через скрипт login.php. Авторизация поддерживается с помощью сессий + SSL. 
А на другом домене нужно сделать эту авторизацию с помощью срипта, и заполучив данные, сохранить у себя в базе (парсер уже моя забота). Это делается для регулярного обновления прайслиста с основных складов. Ничего противозаконного в этом нет.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как с помощью cURL делать авторизацию и поддерживать сессию? После авторизации и получения сессий, надо редирекнуться на другой скрипт, который и выдает прайс.

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем правильно понял ваш вопрос..

Трындел про сервер, а вам клиент нужен.

Посмотрите в [эту сторону](http://www.shkodenko.kiev.ua/index.php?lang_id=1&content_id=165)

Comment: Мысль донесли, а реализацию нет) У меня проблема не с мыслью, а с реализацией. Там все просто. Скрипт авторизуется по SSL каналу, открывает нужный документ, загружает и выдает в обозреватель или в файл. А как это реализовать?

Comment: Радикально изменил ответ))

Comment: Отлично, авторизацию прошел))) а теперь нужно обратиться к другому скрипту сервера имея сессию (все хранится в файле). Не знаю как!)

Answer (score 0):

Если сессия передается через COOKIE - нада дописывать строки при инициализации сеанса

// указываем имя файла для хранения и считывания cookies-файлов 
curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"outfile.txt"); 
curl_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"outfile.txt" );

Была похожая проблема (лет 5 назад) решил именно так - если не поможет отпишите - дальше подумаю

Comment: помогает, у меня так и есть, авторизацю проходит, но дальше идет редирект на другой скрипт. и тут мне показывает тупо заголовки... а надо чтоб он загрузил прайс, который передается другим сриптом после авторизации. Если в браузере открыть страницу и аторизоваться то происходит редирект. А скрипт почему-то не редиктит...

Comment: Хм... НА сколько помню на память - есть в установках опция - принимать перенаправление по умолчанию или нет - опцию не помню - но есть такая! Дома буду гляну

Comment: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION: При установке этого параметра в ненулевое значение, при получении HTTP заголовка "Location: " будет происходить перенаправление на указанный этим заголовком URL (это действие выполняется рекурсивно, для каждого полученного заголовка "Location:").
Пробуй

Comment: Уже, пробовал, еще вчера ночью... никакого результата. Позже напишу подробнее что именно происходит.